# node ffi Rect type

Tags: javascript, node.js, user32, node-ffi

I want to get a specific window's size in node, using the node-ffi and user32 libraries. Can't make the Rect pointer work at all, I'm either getting NULL as output, or fatal errors.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633503(v=vs.85).aspx

*Out* LPRECT lpRect should contain the top left, and bottom right corner's coordinates.

```
var ffi = require('ffi');
var ref = require('ref');
var Struct = require('ref-struct');

var lpctstr = {
    name: 'lpctstr',
    indirection: 1,
    size: ref.sizeof.pointer,
    get: function(buffer, offset) {
        var _buf = buffer.readPointer(offset);
        if(_buf.isNull()) {
            return null;
        }
        return _buf.readCString(0);
    },
    set: function(buffer, offset, value) {
        var _buf = ref.allocCString(value, 'ucs2');

        return buffer.writePointer(_buf, offset);
    },
    ffi_type: ffi.types.CString.ffi_type
};


var lpdwordPtr = ref.refType(ref.types.ulong);

var pointStruct = new Struct({
  'x': 'long',
  'y': 'long'
});

var rectStruct = new Struct({
  left        : pointStruct,
  top         : pointStruct,
  right       : pointStruct,
  bottom      : pointStruct
});

var rectPtr = ref.refType(rectStruct);


var user32 = ffi.Library('user32', {
    FindWindowW: ['int', [lpctstr, lpctstr]],
    GetWindowThreadProcessId: ['int', ['int', lpdwordPtr]],
    SetForegroundWindow: ['bool', ['int']],
    GetWindowRect: [rectPtr, ['int']]
});

var hwnd = user32.FindWindowW(null, 'Calculator');
user32.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
var Rect = user32.GetWindowRect(hwnd);
console.log(JSON.stringify(Rect));
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit late, but I think I finally figured out how GetWindowRect() works.

at first you need to define Rect Struct according to the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windef/ns-windef-rect):

```
const rect = Struct({
  left : 'long',
  top : 'long',
  right : 'long',
  bottom : 'long',
});
```

then you need to define your user32 library:

```
//I think This is something like (struct rect *)
//because you need to path pointer of struct rect to this function
const rectPtr = ref.refType(rect);

var user32 = ffi.Library('user32.dll', {
                        GetForegroundWindow : ['long',[]],
                        GetWindowRect : ['bool',['long',rectPtr]]
});
```

before calling GetWindowRect it's necessary to acquire handle of the window you want to know the size of. Lets just take currently active window for simplicity by calling [GetForegroundWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getforegroundwindow) function:

```
const wind_handle = user32.GetForegroundWindow();
```

We have a window handle and now we need do create actual rect struct for GetWindowRect() to store result in:

```
const rec_struct = new rect;
```

if you log this object in console you'll see something like this:

> { left: 0,
>     top: 0,
>     right: 0,
>     bottom: 0,
>   'ref.buffer': 
>            Buffer@0x000001C387A81E80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 }

as I mentioned GetWindowRect accepts buffer as it's second parameter and sets it's contents with the contents of actual C rectangle structure. so to get window information in our rec_struct object we need to path rec_struct['ref.buffer'] to the GetWindowRect :

```
user32.GetWindowRect(fhwnd,rec['ref.buffer']);
```

now if you log rec_struct in the console, you'll get it filled with the the coordinates of window's upper-left and lower-right corners:

> { left: 560,
>     top: 220,
>     right: 1360,
>     bottom: 820,
>     'ref.buffer':
>      Buffer@0x0000012F3751F270 30 02 00 00 dc 00 00 00 50 05 00 00 34 03 00 00 }

Now calculation of the window size will be trivial.

Comment: Instead of `rec_struct['ref.buffer']`, you can also use `rec_struct.ref()`.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get your example working using the `ref-struct` approach, but I figured out a way to do it using a simple "pointer" type:

```
var user32 = new ffi.Library("user32", {
    GetWindowRect: ["bool", ["int32", "pointer"]],
});

export function GetWindowRect(handle: number) {
    var rectPointer = Buffer.alloc(4 * 4);
    var success = user32.GetWindowRect(handle, rectPointer);
    if (!success) return null;
    
    let rect = RectPointerToRect(rectPointer);
    console.log("Rect: " + JSON.stringify(rect));
    return rect;
}

function RectPointerToRect(rectPointer: Buffer) {
    let rect = {} as any;
    rect.left = rectPointer.readUInt32LE(0);
    rect.top = rectPointer.readUInt32LE(4);
    rect.right = rectPointer.readUInt32LE(8);
    rect.bottom = rectPointer.readUInt32LE(12);
    return rect;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I believe, you have made four POINTs for RECT, but it needs only LONG.

```
var ffi = require('ffi');
var ref = require('ref');
var Struct = require('ref-struct');

var lpctstr = {
    name: 'lpctstr',
    indirection: 1,
    size: ref.sizeof.pointer,
    get: function(buffer, offset) {
        var _buf = buffer.readPointer(offset);
        if(_buf.isNull()) {
            return null;
        }
        return _buf.readCString(0);
    },
    set: function(buffer, offset, value) {
        var _buf = ref.allocCString(value, 'ucs2');

        return buffer.writePointer(_buf, offset);
    },
    ffi_type: ffi.types.CString.ffi_type
};


var lpdwordPtr = ref.refType(ref.types.ulong);

var pointStruct =  Struct({
  'x': ffi.types.ulong,
  'y': ffi.types.ulong
});

var rectStruct =  Struct({
  left        : ffi.types.ulong,
  top         : ffi.types.ulong,
  right       : ffi.types.ulong,
  bottom      : ffi.types.ulong
});

var rectPtr = ref.refType(rectStruct);


var user32 = ffi.Library('user32', {
    FindWindowW: ['int', [lpctstr, lpctstr]],
    GetWindowThreadProcessId: ['int', ['int', lpdwordPtr]],
    SetForegroundWindow: ['bool', ['int']],
    GetWindowRect: ['bool', ['int',rectStruct]]
});

var hwnd = user32.FindWindowW(null, 'E');
user32.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
var Rect = new rectStruct;
var bool = user32.GetWindowRect(hwnd, Rect);
console.log(JSON.stringify(Rect), Rect);
```